# ¿Es necesario montar mi base de datos al algún servidor host?

Tags: c#, webservice, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Yo cree una página web con un CRUD sencillo, la monté al IIS sin necesidad de montar a la base de datos ya que en el archivo web.config tengo los datos de conexión y está encriptados, además cualquier equipo que esté dentro de mi misma red pueden ingresar a la página web.

Ahora mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo hacer esto mismo en un hosting gratuito para probar su comportamiento sin necesidad de montar mi base de datos?

Hago esta pregunta ya que los vídeos que he visto veo que siempre montan una base de datos, y si es así, al montarlo está siempre se mantendrá sincronizada con mi base de datos local?

Espero que me puedan ayudar con mi duda, quedo atento a sus respuestas.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario tener una base de datos accesible desde el hosting que utilices ya que deduzco que tendrías 2 ambientes: localhost(tu Pc) y producción (hosting gratuito); y ambos no tendrían una comunicación directa. La base de datos de localhost podría ser accedida desde producción siempre y cuando, tengas creada una regla de firewall para permitir una comunicación con la base de datos y crear reglas de puertos desde el router, sin mencionar el tema de contar con una IP estática, temas de dns. Por fortuna los hosting te brindan también servicios de base de datos por lo cual no tienes que lidiar con lo anterior y funcionará de maravillas con tu web. Si optas por eso, deberás cambiar tu cadena de conexión con la del hosting y volverla a encriptar.
Espero haber despejado tu duda.